# get the count of all repeated substring in a string with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to get all repeated substrings of a specific length in a string and their count.
Example:
string = "abcabcabcdabcd"

```
get_repeats(string, 3 #length of the substrings)
```

output:

```
abc (4)
bca (2)
cab (2)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Please send your code, as we only solve problems with implementations, not solve the whole question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

def get_repeats(s, k):
    ctr = Counter(s[i:i+k] for i in range(len(s) - k + 1))
    return {sub: c for sub, c in ctr.items() if c > 1}
```

And usage:

```
>>> get_repeats("abcabcabcdabcd", 3)
{'abc': 4, 'bca': 2, 'cab': 2}
```

Comment: Like a charm, Thank you sir.